# Different sized menubuttons on a single page

Tags: css

I have 3 menubuttons on my page. I would like to have different widths for each of them. For this, I did the following:

```
<style>
  .ui-menu {
    width : 180px;
  }
</style>
```

However, this sets the width of all menubuttons to 180px. I would like to have widths 180px, 140px and 160px respectively. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have some unique identifier to each ( eg an `id` ) and use that to style them. Alternatively, you can use CSS3 `:nth-child` ([documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)) selector, but it's probably overkill for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
.ui-menu:nth-child(1){
width : 180px;
}

.ui-menu:nth-child(2){
width : 140px;
}

.ui-menu:nth-child(3){
width : 160px;
}
</style>
```